# Flutter app on Linux missing title bar icons when run from within VSCode terminal; works fine in normal shell

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, gtk

I am building a Flutter app in VSCode. When I run it from the terminal provided by VSCode via `flutter run -d linux`, the app runs fine but shows three generic icons in the title bar in the place where the minimize, full-screen, and close buttons should be:

[image: broken title bar screenshot]

In addition, this message is displayed in the terminal that I launched the app from: `Gtk-WARNING **: 19:56:49.586: Could not find the icon 'window-minimize-symbolic-ltr'. The 'hicolor' theme was not found either, perhaps you need to install it.`

When I run the same command in the same directory within a normal Bash terminal, the app's title bar appears as I expect:

[image: expected title bar screenshot]

The `glxgears` app looks correct in *both* terminals:

[image: glxgears title bar screenshot]

When I compare the output of `set` in these two environment, I could not find any differences that might explain the different behavior. I also tried to `unset` all of the environment variables mentioning GTK in the VSCode environment, but this didn't help.

I don't know if this is related, but Ubuntu, VSCode, and the app are all running in an LXC container with X11 enabled (based on [Running X11 software in LXD containers](https://blog.simos.info/running-x11-software-in-lxd-containers/)). I access the container via `lxc exec my_container -- sudo -u ubuntu -i`

**How can I run the app from the VSCode terminal so that the app title bar icons work properly?**